# How do i go about making a django model field unique but only for individual users?

Tags: django, django-models

So I have this watchlist model

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='watchlist')
    symbol = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

Where a user and a text symbol is saved. A user is not allowed to save two of the same symbol cuz that wouldnt be good logic. Thats why i added the `unique=True`. However, I later realized that i kinda misunderstood what unique does and that its unique across the whole table no matter who the user is.

I only want it to be unique when the user is the same.

So Test_User can save "ABC" and "DEF" but cant save "ABC" again.
However User123 should be allowed to save "ABC" and so on.

One bad solution to this would be taking care of it in my views when i save instances by getting a list of symbols saved already and checking if the given symbol is in that list or not and save accordingly. I consider this a bad solution because it wont work in admin and the redundancy will be insane if i need to use it in other views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unique_together field in Meta class for your model. For example:

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='watchlist')
   symbol = CharField(max_length=10)
   
   class Meta:
      unique_together = 'user', 'symbol'
```

Also link to Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`UniqueConstraint`**[Django-Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#fields) to restrict the user to not use the same symbol again.

```
from django.db import models

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="watchlist")
    symbol = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["user", "symbol"], name="user_symbol")
        ]
```

Comment: that looks like it can also work but i might prefer using unique-together that Amen said. Thanks anyway

Comment: you can use `unique_together` for now but keep in mind `unique_together` may be deprecated in the future as stated in Django docs.